# How much ipad time do most kids get?

Tags: toddler, development, siblings, tablet-computer

I'm a mother of 2, ages 3 and 10.
I am worried that my youngest child is spending as much time, sometimes more time, on the iPad than my eldest.

The iPad seems ideal when I am busy and the kids are content when using it, however I don't want to over do their computer time especially for my youngest.

Am I right to be concerned? I'm wondering what time periods parents are seeing their kids using iPads for?